# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[4200]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ip_address=::1' at line 1 in D:\Xampp\htdocs\SK Tuning\cart.php:133 Stack trace: #0 D:\Xampp\htdocs\SK Tuning\cart.php(133): PDO->query('UPDATE cart_det...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Xampp\htdocs\SK Tuning\cart.php on line 133

Here is my code:

```
                 <?php 
                    $get_ip_add=getIPAddress();
                    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
                        $quantities=$_POST['qty'];
                       $update_cart="UPDATE cart_details SET quantity=$quantities WHERE                         ip_address='$get_ip_add'";
                        $result_products_quantity=$con->query($update_cart);
                        $total_price=$total_price*$quantities;
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: You should use bound parameters as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: You will probably find that `$quantities` is empty.